# Real date for today with nib file

Tags: objective-c, ios

How I create label with real date for today with nib file?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and also what do you mean by "with nib file"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it straight in Interface Builder, you have to do it programmatically. You should connect (Google something like 'IBOutlet') the UILabel and then add this code, for instance in viewDidLoad (where _label is your linked UILabel):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];
```